# Convergent sequences in $l^2$ and sequences of inner products

Tags: real-analysis

If $x^{(k)}\rightarrow x$ and $y^{(k)}\rightarrow y$ in $l^2$, we need to show that $\left \langle x^{(k)},y^{(k)}\right\rangle\rightarrow \left\langle x,y\right\rangle$. I've tried a bunch of things but seem to get stuck with a sum where im left with the terms $x_n^{(k)}$ and $y_n$ summed from $n=1,\dots$ and eventhough these do go to 0, i dont think thats enough.

---

If you want to avoid continuity, you can always use the fact that, if $k\in\mathbb N$, then\begin{align}\bigl\lvert\langle x^{(k)},y^{(k)}\rangle-\langle x,y\rangle\bigr\rvert&=\bigl\lvert\langle x,y^{(k)}-y\rangle+\langle x^{(k)}-x,y\rangle+\langle x^{(k)}-x,y^{(k)}-y\rangle\bigr\rvert\\&\leqslant\lVert x\rVert\lVert y^{(k)}-y\rVert+\lVert x^{(k)}-x\rVert\lVert y\rVert+\lVert x^{(k)}-x\rVert\lVert y^{(k)}-y\rVert.\end{align}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$|\langle x^{(k)},y^{(k)} \rangle -\langle x, y \rangle|$ $=|\langle x^{(k)},y^{(k)} \rangle -\langle x,y^{(k)} \rangle+\langle x,y^{(k)} \rangle -\langle x, y \rangle|$ $\leq |\langle x^{(k)},y^{(k)} \rangle -\langle x,y^{(k)}|+|\langle x,y^{(k)} \rangle -\langle x, y \rangle|$. This is $\leq \|x^{(k)}-x\|\|y^{(k)}\|+\|x\|\|y^{(k)}-y\|$. Let $k \to \infty$. Note that $\|y^{(k)}\|$ is bounded because $\|y^{(k)}\| \leq \|y^{(k)}-y\|+\|y\|$.

Comment: These inequalities definitely hold if you take the $||\cdot||_1$ norm, but how do you know it holds for the norm in $l^2$?

Comment: Oh that would be CZ ofcourse, I just answered it myself.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the fact that $(x,y)\mapsto\langle x,t\rangle$ is continuous. So, if $\lim_{k\to\infty}x^{(k)}=x$ and $\lim_{k\to\infty}y^{(k)}=y$, then $\lim_{k\to\infty}\bigl(x^{(k)},y^{(k)}\bigr)=(x,y)$ and therefore $\lim_{k\to\infty}\langle x^{(k)},y^{(k)}\rangle=\langle x,y\rangle$.

Comment: Yes it is simple if done like this, but the book has not discussed continuity yet. So I reckon they're after a more direct proof.